# Debug Tornado app running in Minikube

Tags: tornado, minikube

I develop in PyCharm on macOS. I wish to step through my code running on Tornado inside a container running in Minikube on my local machine. With PHP/Apache I used to use Xdebug which worked seamlessly. Is there is a similar solution for a Python/Tornado setup?